# How to avoid WARNING in Circular dependency detected: with modals

Tags: angular

I'm using ngx-bootstrap modals and I have 4 modals: `LoginModal` , `RegisterModal` , `CreateNewPasswordModal`, `RestorePasswordModal`. The plan is following. I click `Log-in` button in header and I open LoginModal.
**header**

```
<span (click)="openModalLogin(true)">Log-in</span>
openModalLogin() {this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(AuthorizationModalComponent);}
```

Then in `LoginModal` I can click the button registration and it opens `RegistrationModal` or I can press the button `I forgot the password` and it opens `RestorePasswordModal`.
**LoginModal**

```
<button (click)="openModalRestorePassword()">Forgot password</button>
<button  type="button" (click)="openRegistrationModal()" class="reg__cancel">Registration</button>
      openRegistrationModal(): void {
        this.closeModal();
        this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(RegistrationModalComponent);
      }
    
      openModalRestorePassword(): void {
        this.closeModal();
        this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(RestorePasswordModalComponent);
      }
```

And etc. So as you can see I import modals directly to components to open them . Everything works perfect but I have the following warnings

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
> src\app\layout\header\modals\authorization-modal\authorization-modal.component.ts
> -> src\app\layout\header\modals\registration-modal\registration-modal.component.ts
> -> src\app\layout\header\modals\authorization-modal\authorization-modal.component.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
> src\app\layout\header\modals\create-new-password-modal\create-new-password-modal.component.ts
> -> src\app\layout\header\modals\restore-password-modal\restore-password-modal.component.ts
> -> src\app\layout\header\modals\create-new-password-modal\create-new-password-modal.component.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
> src\app\layout\header\modals\registration-modal\registration-modal.component.ts
> -> src\app\layout\header\modals\authorization-modal\authorization-modal.component.ts
> -> src\app\layout\header\modals\registration-modal\registration-modal.component.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
> src\app\layout\header\modals\restore-password-modal\restore-password-modal.component.ts
> -> src\app\layout\header\modals\authorization-modal\authorization-modal.component.ts
> -> src\app\layout\header\modals\restore-password-modal\restore-password-modal.component.ts

How can I solve this issue ? At first time I was using all models in header component and it wasn't any warning as it was 1 component but code was looked very huge and I have decided to split all modals in differenct components

Comment: There should be a master and a slave. Here, both modals are master. Have to look to what is called `dumb components`, and use `@Output()`s

Comment: But how should I split to dumb components ? Each model has own functionality as f.e loginModal has login() function wich login user , registration makes all staff related to registration

Comment: Well, modals are quite tricky, since you should not open multiples modals at once. So opening a modal should close the previous one. So you may need a parent component handling all this. So when you open modal A, if the modal A wants to open modal B, it doesn't open it, it sends an event to the master component asking to open modal B. So the master component will close modal A, and open modal B. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Yes , it make sense. So it means that all models should exist inside parent. I was trying to do somethiing like that, but it was a service and it was a bad idea as I had to emit a value for log-in click and then when the user click again event is not submeted until u will not make old emiision to false. Anyhow thanks , I'm trying to do other options of this task

Comment: anyhow I was trying to avoid much code in one file , form for each modal but it seems like I can not do that right now

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to delegate opening the new modals to a `header` component.

`LoginModal` should have output events like `@Output() openRestoreModal` and `@Output() openRegistrationModal`, subscribing to which in `header` you would be able to open any new modal or do anything else.

Same for other components.

---

There's also an option with service (which in my opinion is not really good here):

1. Create a service with a `Subject` fo each your modal, like `openLoginModalSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>()` (Note: `BehaviourSubject` is not suitable here)
2. Subscribe to these subject in the component to open up proper modal on new event - `modalsService.openLoginModal.subscribe(() => {//open modal here})`
3. Use this service in each modal to trigger proper event like that `modalsService.openLoginModal.next()`

Pay attention that we can't open modals just in the service cause it will create a circular dependency again (modals will be using the service, the service will be using modals)